# Job Title from list?

Tags: custom-fields

Is it possible to select the **Job Title** from a closed list only ?

- Choice1
- Choice2
- Choice3

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. It is worth giving some more details of your process flow and what you are trying to achieve. Bari

Answer (score 4):

You can't easily change the standard 'job title' field but you could simply create a custom field as a select list and use that instead.

Comment: Or use Caldera Forms and I assume with webforms and make a select list and then map to Job Title field. Depends on how you are capturing data.

Comment: Caldera for WP, or Webforms for Drupal (note Caldera has end-of-life coming to be replaced by other WP form builder)